# Why is Xcode placing this array all in one line of code

Tags: swift, xcode

Notice how the array is all under `line #10`

There was a long list of words that I used a function in playgrounds to convert into a string. I then copied and pasted that string to a swift file in my project. And ever since I've been getting some funky behavior whenever I
A) Scroll this file
B) Access the array via a function

Anyone have a better solution.. All I can think is manually inputting the data.. but we're talking 4,000 words here..

[image]

Comment: Why is Xcode placing it on one line? Because there aren't any newline characters in it. Option 1) Use find and replace to change `,` to `,\n`. Option 2) Load this data from a JSON file instead of storing it in code.

Comment: A) Xcode is having to manually wrap the large line, so you are bound to get some lag. B) It is a big array, maybe you could show the function that uses it.

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of having data in a separate Swift file?

Answer (score 4):

Swift really does not like long array literals (and neither, as you are saying, does Xcode).

What I would do is write a little program to convert the list into a *.plist* file, and include that file in my app bundle. Now the only code in your app would be to *load* that file (as an array).

Comment: Thanks, any references to that, (the program to convert into a plist) I have never done that before.

Comment: How to write it would depend on the form of your original file containing the word list. Actually, it may be that the original file is just a return-separated list, in which case you could load _that_ and split into an array by line. The point of my suggestion is merely: don't use a literal array at all; use the _data_.